# Ajax call too slow ? Javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, request

I am setting up a registration form.
This form has 7 fields that are being tested for validation.
2 of them have a special validation; I have an Ajax call to a PHP class where I send an email_string to this class, testing, if such an email already exists in my database (evading duplicates).

```
params = {};
params['source'] = 'checkEMail';
params['email']  = email
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : 'some_class.php',
    data : params,
    success: function(msg)
    {
        if(msg > 0) /* email exists */
            is_error = true;
    }
});
```

And in my PHP Class I got something like this:

```
$final = mysql_fetch_assoc(foo);
echo ($final) ? 1 : 0;
```

I was testing the data and in fact - I get '1' if the email exists and '0' if it does not.

Funny thing is, that this snippet works fine **AS LONG AS** there are **other** errors in this form - like an empty username.
The "is_error" is a boolean that is set to false at the beginning of the script and if one validation fails, it gets true.
Then, finally, I got this:

```
if(is_error)
{
    error.show();
    error.empty().append('some html foo');
}
else
{
    $('form').submit();
    error.empty().hide();
}
```

So how can it be that I the form will be send although is_error is set to true?
Only reason I could think of is that the form is being send before the "is_error" is being testet - but the send of the form is at the very bottom of the script.

Oh and I am calling it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("#reg_submit").click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
                checkReg();
            });
</script>
```

Comment: use console.log(is_error) or alert(is_error) before the submit() to check if you have a race condition.  How are you calling the ajax? on page load? or on a submit event?

Comment: alert(is_error) is saying "true" as long as there are other fields also wrong. I've added another boolean and changed the final if to 'if(is_error || email_exists) ... else if(!is_error && !email_exists) but now, the form isn't send at all.
I am calling checkReg() while submitting - and in this function, there's the ajax call.

Comment: But do you get false if the other fields are right? then you are having a race condition, that's why the form is submitting, you should do the submit after the ajax request is completed, see my solution below, try it and tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Yeah just like you said ... putting the code under "complete" did the stuff, very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of having the `if(is_error){` part at the end of the script, I would suggest you to do it in the ajax request completion to avoid race conditions:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'some_class.php',
    data: params,
    success: function(msg) {
        if (msg > 0) /* email exists */
        is_error = true;
    },
    complete: function() {
        if (is_error) {
            error.show();
            error.empty().append('some html foo');
        } else {
            $('form').submit();
            error.empty().hide();
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you, this is actually working. Even without the json_encode part. thank you very much :) :)

Comment: You are welcome, check $.ajax() in the jquery page, as it has options to handle different steps of the call, like when you got errors back and things like that, very helpful to handle correctly the requesets.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is caused by different output types that you are trying to match...

First, change your PHP output to

```
echo json_encode($final ? true : false);
```

Then, to work with JSON, I would add this line to ajax calling method, to be sure...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    ...
    success: function(msg)
    {
        if(msg!==true){
            is_error = true;
        }
    }
});
```